# How to calculate how many rectangles fit in a polygon?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm creating an algorithm using JavaScript + Canvas, the user can draw a polygon, after it I want to calculate how many rectangles (suppose I know the dimensions) fit inside this polygon?

For example, I have 3 examples of a yellow polygon (rectangle, triangle, and a complex), I want to know how many rectangles fit inside it.

[image: Example of polygon]

Comment: Sorry, but this question is to broad and with no code, can you show what you tried and explain where are you getting stuck ... you should read: 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Now on the problem you ask, my guess is what you really want to know is the maximum amount of rectangles that can fit inside a polygon ... don't underestimate this problem, this is a complex optimization task, you might want to look at some of the algorithms available: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms#Optimization_algorithms ... if what you need is just a crude approximation you can randomly place the first rectangle inside the polygon and then add other rectangles to the sides as long as they don't go out of the boundaries of the polygon

Comment: @Lucas the calculations for a rectangle and a triangle would be rather simple - the tricky part are arbitrary shapes. The user should be able to draw **any** kind of shape?

Comment: @obscure Yes, but they generally are triangle, rectangle, rhombus, parallelogram, and trapezoid.

Answer (score 1):

### If rectangles can be cut

The area of a rectangle is width * height.

The area of any polygon with straight edges can be found from the set of points that define the vertices using the function below. Half the sum of the cross products of vertices defining each edge.

```
const polyArea = points => {
    var i = 0, area = 0, len = points.length;
    while (i < len) { 
        const p1 = points[i++];
        const p2 = points[i % len];
        area += p1.x * p2.y - p1.y * p2.x;
    }
    return Math.abs(0.5 * area);
}
// example
const triangleArea = polyArea([{x:100, y:0}, {x: 200, y: 200}, {x: 0, y: 200}]);
```

The max number of rectangles that can fit in a polygon is the `polygonArea / rectangleArea`.

### If rectangles can not be cut

However the actual number of rectangles will be some value from 0 to the number calculated above.

There is no simple solution to the problem apart from the brute force approach of placing rectangles in different patterns to see which pattern is the best fit. For each polygon there is an infinite number of patterns that can be used, thus any solution will be just the best of many guess if you want id done before lunch.